# Error with Serverless Framework Deployment

Tags: python, lambda, serverless-framework, binance

**Background**: I have been working in Python to create a lambda function that will hit the Binance API to fetch balances and transactions. To deploy, I have been using the Serverless Framework (https://serverless.com/) and virtualenv which has made it a breeze up until this point. I have 2 other functions working perfect with other exchanges.

**Error**: When I deploy, I am getting the following:

```
Unable to import module 'getBinanceTransactions': No module named '_regex'
```

getBinanceTransactions being the function I created to return what I want. Nothing crazy, just following the python-binance documentation (https://github.com/sammchardy/python-binance) to grab all transactions and then data wrangling.

*Note that this works on my local machine!*

I do a serverless deploy, and everything updates just fine using serverless-python-requirements to package everything separately. Here are my imports (only 2 external packages):

```
from __future__ import print_function
import json
from binance.client import Client
import pymysql
```

And my requirements.txt, with both this and the code separated in a directory just like the other I have working in a similar format:

```
PyMySQL==0.9.2
python_binance==0.6.9
```

I have been searching for the solution but no one has seem to run into this problem. It also seems that _regex is a code method to Python which makes the situation even more strange.

I have tried wiping my virtualenv out and rebuilding, rebuilding the entire file structure, pip freeze >> requirements.txt on installing both packages to make sure nothing was missed, changing the name of the imports and requirements, importing regex/re in my function, even switching to Python 2.7 for a hail mary. Nothing seems to work (despite the others working) and I get the same error every time.

Does anyone have any ideas?